# Air Intake hose

Tags: hyundai, sonata

I've searched all over the internet for something that would replicate my current Air Intake hose, sadly, i cannot find anything.

I own a 01' Hyundai Sonata, 2.4L. When I blow smoke through it ( when it was attached) i didn't see any leaks, however I heard a hissing noise. But is it possible that I can use any type of air intake hose, as long as it has a connection to fit for the MAF? I also cleaned the MAF and i don't think it's a bad sensor, as i've tested it.

I literally couldn't find any website with this listed, but here's what it looks like:

[image]

it's very worn out on the outside, but i looked on the inside of it, and it just looks perfect, and I couldn't find a crack.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

I think I can come up with four options for you:

1. Get some rubber cement and run a small bead around all of the connection points of the hose to make sure they are sealed. Ensure you clean the rubber very well prior to putting any sealant on it.
2. Go to a junk yard (or look online) for a replacement.
3. Find an aftermarket cold air intake as a replacement.
4. If all else fails, go the the dealership and order a new one.